# sql find newly loaded id's before dropping tabel

Tags: mysql

Goodday,

I have a rather generic question which is more of an analytical question which requires a technical implementation.

I have table that gets renewed every day by dropping the table after which the same query as yesterday is being ran to repopulate the same tabel. each record does hold a unique id that gets loaded and a date at which it gets loaded (with sysdate).

now I wish to gather some analytical data to see how many records are loaded each day and how many new records are loaded that were not loaded yesterday. the latter question is where my question resides. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You says that your table has a date field which records the date at which the row was inserted. You can simply fetch the rows using that date field.

1. Fetch the rows using date of yesterday and today.
2. Find the complement of their intersection.(Gives rows that were not updated yesterday as well as today of both days).
3. Find the intersection of previous result with that of rows updated
   today.(This eliminates the rows updated yesterday.).